# How can i pass a state from one react route to another react route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am building an app with multiple routes so as you can guess i need to transfer data between different routes, I am using `react-router-dom` to navigate/redirect between those routes using `useHistory.push("/route")` is there any way that the states in one of my route could be accessed by my another route as they are located in different modules as shown below

```
<Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/">
                <Home/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path = "/login">
                <Login/>
            </Route>    
            <Route exact path = "/signup">
                <Signup/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

so can anyone tell me how can I send some states from /login to /home etc
any help is appreciated..

Comment: the same way you always do this in React, by ["lifting state up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to your top-level component. The fact your child components are `Route`s doesn't change this at all. If this is too much boilerplate you could look into using React Context, or a state-management library like Redux.

Comment: I actually never tried this `lifting up` on route change, simply I'm afraid of page refresh. Of course if you don't see a hard refresh, this isn't a bad approach, especially if `Context` is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, there're ways.

#### Url state

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
 
const Component = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  ...
  history.push('/bulletin', { type: 'success' });
}
```

This `type` will show up under that route

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Component = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const { type } = location.state
```

#### Local storage

Save it somewhere in local storage inside browser and then next route pick it up.

#### Server storage

Call an api to save that info, so next route will pick it up via another api call.

#### Coupled way

All above are decoupled way which should be scalable. Sometimes you can wire two routes physically together, ex. just reuse it again the second component in first component.

Comment: this made things much easier i thought there would be very much trouble for that