# How to pass data fetched from an API as props to a component whose routes is defined in another page in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, react-functional-component

I am using functional component for this and axios for api call

Comment: add code for whatever you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem yesterday I have asked the same question here is the link to it check it and if you need further clarification do let me know

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405036/how-can-i-pass-a-state-from-one-react-route-to-another-react-route?noredirect=1#comment119144769_67405036)

Comment: Thanks, there were many solution, what worked for you?

Comment: passing data along with routes as like history.push("/route", {data});  where data is itself a javascript object and then at that route you can acess the data